# How to say that a research topic is applicable for different purposes?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests

I want to say that my research topic is applicable for different purposes, or I can do a lot of things with my research work, or I have worked on a research topic which has a lot of application.

How can I say it? multi-purpose research topic? or versatile research topic? what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should concentrate more on finding the desired adjective to describe your “research work” or better yet your “research **results**” than on finding one to describe your “research topic,” because based on the way you describe your “research topic,” I think it sounds like a “*general* research topic,” which really doesn’t give the positive spin that I’m sure you are after.

Here’s one way that you could perhaps put a positive spin on having [had] a “general” topic while using either (or both) of your two good suggestions (“multi-purpose and “versatile”) to describe the “results” that you achieved:

> “The topic of my research was/is sufficiently general (or “just
>   general enough”) to permit me to work on multiple applications/issues
>   and achieve multi-purpose/[and] versatile results.”

Answer (score 0):

You kinda already have.

It has a plethora of practical purposes.  A multitude of meanings.  When I get alliterative in my writing it usually means I'm not being challenged enough and so am bored.  Just list what it might be good for and move on.

Comment: I am looking for an adjective,  adj + research topic

Comment: fine, multi-faceted?

Comment: I think it is more about aspects of something rather than its applications

Comment: I was thinking of an application as being an aspect of the research.  Much research doesn't care about applications at all.

Comment: I mean this research is a tool, you can do lots of things using it

Comment: I knew that the moment you said your research topic is applicable for different purposes.  All the best answers are already in your question.